# mysql- Display a list of users sorted according to the time

Tags: mysql

I have a page wherein I would like to display the list of user who have signed up for the paid subscription.

The list should be sorted according to the `subscribed_time` row present in another table called `paid_subs`.

This is the query I am using

```
SELECT * 
  FROM user 
 WHERE EXISTS
     ( SELECT * 
         FROM paid_subs 
        WHERE paid_subs.user_id= user.id 
        ORDER 
           BY paid_subs.subscribed_time DESC)
```

What the above query is doing is simply giving me the list of users who have a paid subscription.

I would like the query to display the list of paid subscriber in a `subscribed_time` sorted order.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

`Exists` simply check if the corresponding records exists and returns a true or false result. If you want to order by a field from another table, then you must use a join.

```
SELECT * FROM user
INNER JOIN paid_subs ON paid_subs.user_id= user.id
ORDER BY paid_subs.subscribed_time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to do a [JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) between the two tables on user_id. [Inner Join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) will ensure that only those users are considered, which have paid for the subscription.
- Now, do a simple [Order By](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/) to sort the data based on subscription time.
- Also, you should fetch only specific fields (as per your application code requirements), instead of using wildcard (`*`). Do read: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Use the following query:

```
SELECT u.*  -- please change this to specific fields, eg: u.id, u.name etc 
FROM user AS u 
INNER JOIN paid_subs ps ON ps.user_id = u.id 
ORDER BY ps.subscribed_time DESC
```